# A generic error occurred in GDI+. How to fix?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have seen this error pop up everywhere, but most of the answers don't seem to work for me. I am trying to save a `PictureBox` image to a directory. The code I have`PictureBox1.Image.Save("C:\Users\khale\OneDrive\Pictures\Screenshots")`. It is very simple and I thought it would work because there were no errors or warnings. I press run and run the function that calls the code, and bam, error pops up. Thanks for reading, bye.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have provided a folder path rather than a file path. There can be other reasons for that exception but that would be one reason.

Comment: Wow that was fast, I will try the file path and see

Comment: But what if I am trying to save multiple pictures would I just have to keep making new file paths

Comment: Well the error doesn't pop up, but it saves as a weird text language, no images

Comment: Yes you would. The system won't come up with file names for you. If you want to be able to use similar names but numbered, e.g. "image1.jpg", "image2.jpg", etc, then you can write code to do that.

Comment: PictureBox1.Image.Save("C:\Users\khale\OneDrive\Pictures\Screenshots\image\" & My.Settings.NumOfPosts & ".jpeg")

Comment: "it saves as a weird text language". Nope. All files are bytes and each file type requires that those bytes be interpreted appropriately. What probably happened is that you saved the file without an extension or with an extension that isn't a standard image format and then tried to open the file from File Explorer. If you do that, Windows uses the file extension to decide how to interpret the bytes. If you read an image file as text then of course you'd get gibberish. You need to save the the correct extension and then it will open automatically as expected.

Comment: Did you open a JPG image in the first place? If you specifically want to save as a JPG then use an overload of `Save` that let's you do that. As it is, you're probably saving as BMP or PNG format with a ".jpg" extension.